# How to make changeable theme (like changing brand color and so on) of the site made with bootstrap using .less file

Tags: html, asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I've my asp site made using bootstrap as a client side CSS framework. I am trying to develop a functionality where user can change his sites brand color and so on.. And these changes should be permanent. I've a little information about less and know this can be done using less file. But having trouble to configure .less according to user settings and compile it to css and make changes permanent. Please suggest me any reference articles for getting started with this functionality. I googled but not found any much useful resources.

Answer (score 0):

load different css files for different color scheme, and store it on the client local storage using HTML 5 local storage.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/change-style-sheets.shtml

Comment: User will choose the brand color from color picker so there are no predefined colors. Hence it is not possible to have predefined style sheets. What I want depending on the color chosen by the user the less file should be compiled and generate new bootstrap css